# How do I install a python deb package for Python3 on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu

I downloaded a deb package `panda3d1.9_1.9.3-xenial_amd64.deb` and I want to install it for Python 3. My OS is Linux Ubuntu 16.04. The default python is 2.7.12 and I would prefer to keep it as default, but Python 3 is installed too and available to use. How do I install this package for Python 3 only?

I am not sure `pip` may help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install pip with Python 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587507/how-to-install-pip-with-python-3)

Comment: @HuyVo I've got a deb package instead. I'm not sure `pip` may help.

Comment: That's not for you to choose but the packager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the package was built to only support Python 2, there is no straightforward way to install it for Python 3.  You will want to ask the packager to provide a package built for Python 3 if there isn't one already.

(This replaces my earlier answer, which was incorrect or at least misleading.  Thanks to @Goyo in particular for setting me straight.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sudo dpkg panda3d1.9_1.9.3-xenial_amd64.deb`  it won't affect your default package.

Comment: It didn't work. This approach installs panda3d for the default Python 2.7. But I want to install it for Python 3.