# Python throws error when I tried to install Taurus

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter, taurus

I am new to Taurus , when I tried to install Taurus manually  for the Jmeter by following the below steps(Install Taurus)  throwing error. see the below the screenshot.
I have downloaded Python 2.7.13  and Installed It.

I have downloaded Taurus exe too and run as administrator also didn't work

http://gettaurus.org/docs/Installation/#Installing-Taurus-Manually

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Please advice me what am I missing!

Thanks,
Rajani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) is a separate executable, you should run it in Windows Command Prompt, **not inside** the Python interpreter so open `cmd.exe`, make sure `pip.exe` is installed and is on your system [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) and your installation should succeed.

References:

- [Taurus Installation on Windows](http://gettaurus.org/install/Installation/#Windows)
- [Taurus: A New Star in the Test Automation Tools Constellation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/taurus-new-star-test-automation-tools-constellation)
- Also be aware that there is a separate [Taurus support forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/codename-taurus) where you can reach out to Taurus developers and maintainers.

Comment: I suggest creating `taurus` tag in stackoverflow, so users can tag when they have questions related to it.

Comment: @Dmitri ,as per the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587507/how-to-install-pip-with-python-3  installing  Python 2.7.9+ will automatically installs the pip where I can see C:\Python27\Scripts. After adding the System variable tried to cross check whether pip installed says didn't provide a command. please advise me where am i missing.I have added the screenshots to the original post

Comment: `pip install bzt`

Comment: @Dmitri, throws error  as "install" unknown command when i tried tried the pip install bzt. Error screenshot has been attached to the original post, please see and advise me! Can I run the Taurus exe ?

Comment: @Dmitri, It worked by running the command from the  path  C:\Python27\Scripts>pip install bzt  .See the attached screenshot in the original post.Thanks a lot Dmitri!

Comment: For Python 3.9.4, running inside of Scripts folder didn't solve the issue . C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts