# Syntax Error from 'pip install' in python + command line

Tags: python, api, twitter, pip, pycharm

Okay, so, I'm running Python 3.4.3 with pip 9.0.1, with the setuptools and wheel.

I'm running this inside JetBrains PyCharm Professional 2017.2.3.

The issue I'm having is trying to install the twitter api packages from this tutorial (ya I'm a n00b) http://wiki.openhatch.org/Twitter

I'm struggling with installing the 4 dependencies mentioned in the first part of the tutorial (httplib2, simplejson, oauth2 and python-twitter)

Honestly, I'm just getting back into programming and this is a project I'd like to complete.

So, I need help with:

- Installing pip, and how to use it, and where (python shell or command line or)
- the dev.twitter.com website (and where to find what I need from there)

Any help is massively appreciated and sorry if I sound really n00by, but do correct me where I'm using incorrect terms etc because that's how I learn I guess :)

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587507/how-to-install-pip-with-python-3) to install pip. Make sure you actually do not have it already, because python3x + comes with pip3. if `pip --version` returns an error in your terminal, you don't have it.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't got pip installed, find your python installation file.Execute it and choose **'Change Python Installation'**. Now choose **'pip'** to install and **'add python.exe to path'**. Wait for it to finish. Now run windows command line and type:

```
pip install package_name
```

Sometimes you may experience that a package isn't available on pip or doesn't work.There are 2 common (not always working) ways to install a package without making pip download the file:

1) A package may be available as a .whl file for download.Download it.Now find it and copy its name  .Open a command line in dictionary where it is located and type

```
pip install **now paste the filename and add .whl**'
```

2)A package is available as a zip file.Packages are often packed into a zip file.Download the file and extract it.Open a command line in it's directory.You may see **setup.py** file.Run

```
python setup.py install
```

When finished installing pip and adding python to path,you can run:

```
pip install httplib2 simplejson oauth2 python-twitter
```

Done.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have pip installed, open the command prompt and just type `pip install name_of_the_extension`.

In this case, `pip install httplib2` will install this package.

I believe you have pip installed on your computer, so it shouldn't be a problem to install the 4 packages you need.

Comment: The question asks for help in installing pip. What makes you believe it's already installed?

Comment: Well, you said "I'm running Python 3.4.3 with pip 9.0.1", I understood that you had it already.
[link](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) has all the explanation on how to install pip, a distribution like anaconda could be usefull if you want to have most of the major python distribution.

Comment: I didn't say anything, I'm not the OP

Comment: The question states "so, I need help with: installing pip..."