# python manage.py migrate on terminal then error show?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, database, migration

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 16, in <module>
    "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

Comment: Well did you forget to activate the virtual environment? (it is part of the error message)?

Comment: Here you have answer for the same question...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46210934/importerror-couldnt-import-django

Answer (score 0):

good article to understand PYTHONPATH: https://bic-berkeley.github.io/psych-214-fall-2016/using_pythonpath.html

```
export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/home/user/work/your_django_project"
```