# Django REST Framework - Django capitalized in `pip3 list`

Tags: python, django, module, pip

I'm building an API using Django REST Framework with [this](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/11/22/how-to-implement-token-authentication-using-django-rest-framework.html) tutorial.  I'm getting a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'` error when I try to test `python3 manage.py`.  I've been going through the long list of issues it could be (reinstall django, need to add an `__init__.py` in the root, etc) and someone recommended checking my modules list with `pip3 list`.

Here's what I see:

```
Package             Version
------------------- -------
asgiref             3.3.1
dj-database-url     0.5.0
Django              3.1.4
django-filter       2.4.0
django-heroku       0.3.1
djangorestframework 3.12.2
gunicorn            20.0.4
```

Is there a reason why Django's capitalized?  Could that be why it isn't finding it in `manage.py`?  If so, how do I go about fixing it?

Here's the full error message I'm getting, but it's really general.  The exception is hardcoded:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    ) from exc
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

Comment: are you using virtualenv? What is the result of `django-admin --version`?

Comment: Have you read this SO post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46210934/importerror-couldnt-import-django\

Comment: The name of the distribution package (`Django`) and the name of the import package (`django`) do not necessarily have to match. The distribution package is the thing that you _pip_-install. While the import package is the thing that you import. They are 2 different things. 1 distribution package can contain multiple import packages, and names do not have to match.-- https://sinoroc.github.io/kb/python/packaging.html

Comment: @JPG I'm not using virtualenv, and I'm thinking that's my problem based on the SO you sent.  Not sure why but my tutorial never mentioned using a virtual environment.

`django-admin --version` gives me `3.1.4`.

Comment: @JPG I've never used virtualenv, so it's all brand new to me.  Is there a tutorial you'd recommend?  I'm already pretty deep in a project so I'm hoping to move it smoothly.

Comment: I would keep individual virtual envs for each project, which help us to isolate the dependencies from one-another. Also, I don't remember any *pretty* doc/blog of virtualenv, but you could easily find plenty of the same on the internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While working with a large framework as Django one must always work in a `virtual environment`. Please check if you have your virtual environment activated. If not, then follow the steps:

1. `cd your_working_directory`
2. `virtualenv environment_name` where `environment_name` can be any name you want.
3. `environment_name/Scripts/activate` if on `Windows`

Or `environment_name/bin/activate` if on `MacOS`

Then after activating the environment you can install all the dependencies using pip. i.e `pip install django`

Comment: This seems like great advice.  I've never worked with a `virtual environment` before, so I'm brand new to the steps you gave.  Is there a tutorial you recommend?

I found this one: https://hostadvice.com/how-to/how-to-create-a-virtual-environment-for-your-django-projects-using-virtualenv/

Comment: This ended up solving my problem, so I'm Accepting it despite the downvotes.  It's possible it was downvoted for the following reasons:
1. It didn't mention installing virtualenv (`pip install virtualenv`)
2. Step 2 didn't explain what `environment_name` was.  Turns out it can be anything, just whatever we want the name of our environment to be.
3. Steps 3 and 4 should just be Step 3 with an "or" in it, to show that only one of the two needs to be done.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Sorry if I missed mentioning to ```pip install virtualenv```. But I am glad it solved your problems.