# ImportError : Couldn't import Django

Tags: python, django, windows, manage.py

I have installed django==3.1.4 and activated Venv on my windows machine and it works fine in myBlog project. But today when I try to run the server, got this error

> ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?

but venv is already activated and when I do
`pip freeze > requirements.txt`

It shows

```
asgiref==3.3.4,
Django==3.1.4,
django-crispy-forms==1.11.2,
Pillow==8.2.0,
pytz==2021.1,
sqlparse==0.4.1,
```

I also checked `sys.path`, It shows

> ['', 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python38.zip', 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\DLLs', 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib', 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32', 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\myBlog\venv', 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\myBlog\venv\lib\site-packages']

Please Help to fix this

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46210934/importerror-couldnt-import-django

Comment: Are you sure that your editor is using the python interpreter of venv and not default ?

See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments for VSCode

Comment: Check this also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/250442/django-installed-but-cant-import-django-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks, everybody ..problem fixed ..probably occurred because I did some C drive repair

I got following error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

I did the following steps.. to overcome my error:

1. On my main folder **Check If you have already a "requiremnts.txt" file skip this step** else run this command on terminal : `pip freeze > requirements.txt` ,**if it saves all your packages** **then only do other steps**
2. Delete Venv folder from the main directory.
3. Again install virtual environments and activate Venv.
4. then run this command `pip install -r requirements.txt` this will install all your packages back.
5. Run again `python manage.py runserver` , It will work fine

Answer (score 2):

if you are trying to run the django server from within your IDE makesure that your virtual environment is active inside the IDE as well.