# Need help cleaning up PyQt and python

Tags: python, python-2.7, qt, anaconda, pyqt5

I was trying to install PyQt 5.9 but I have no idea what I'm doing. According to what I've seen I have to download Qt from:

https://qt-project.org

and then SIP (whatever that is...) and PyQt from:

http://www.riverbankcomputing.com

I did all that and Qt weights like 30 Gb...
Now I have to install pyqt but the README.md file says this:

'''INSTALLATION

Check for any other README files in this directory that relate to your
particular platform.  Feel free to contribute a README for your platform or to
provide updates to any existing documentation.

The first step is to configure PyQt5 by running the following command.

```
python configure.py
```

'''

And I have no idea what to do now, I keep getting the 'no such file/directory found' error. 
I went to the directory where I have python installed and I still get the same.

-
I have a Mac and python 3.6
Turns out I have Qt 5.8 already installed, and since I just downloaded 5.9 I'd like to upgrade it but I don't know how. And maybe it's taking up another 30Gb somewhere else.

Also, when I type 'which python' I get 'anaconda/bin/python' and not python 2.7, how do I fix that? also I went to the dir where I have python and have python 2.4, 2.5 and 2.7. Should I just delete the others? and what is SIP??

Comment: If you have Anaconda already, it would be much easier to do `conda install pyqt5`. I'd also recommend using `homebrew`, since you're using a Mac, which allows you to install and upgrade `Qt` easily. And SIP is a tool which automatically generates bindings to compiled libraries (like `Qt`) to be used in Python.

Comment: And how can I delete the old versions? I want free some memory space also @bnaecker

Comment: If you know where the version(s) are installed, just `rm -r /path/to/qt`. Or delete them from Finder, if that's more convenient.

Answer (score 1):

### **Check these steps**

1. Go to the QT [website](https://qt-project.org) and download it.
2. Install python on your pc,
3. If it's Linux: sudo apt-get install python3.6
4. Or see this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/865554/how-do-i-install-python-3-6-using-apt-get).
5. Install also some IDLE to work on, I'd recommend you to use [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/)
6. You can install now your PyQt through your Pycharm, see in [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html), find for pyqt5.
7. There is always the option to install through [pip3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587507/how-to-install-pip-with-python-3), try to use pip3 instead of pip, since you are using python3.
8. After having pip3, try now to install your pyqt5. [Check it out](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/installation.html).
9. Now you have an IDLE to work on with PyQt and Qt in your machine, maybe you have to say in your PyCharm that you will use python3.6 as your interpreter.