# Error when installing scapy

Tags: python, scapy, python-packaging

Ok so i'm trying to install scapy for python3, but ive been having some issues

when I enter this command:
`pip install scapy`
This is the output:

```
Collecting scapy
Using cached scapy-2.3.3.tgz
In the tar file C:\Users\MYNAME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-oao3meyq-
unpack\scapy-2.3.3.tgz the member scapy-2.3.3/README
is invalid: unable to resolve link inside archive
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\MYNAME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-
  qjegdxw6\scapy\setup.py", line 36
    os.chmod(fname, 0755)
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid token

----------------------------------------
 Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in 
 C:\Users\MYNAME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-qjegdxw6\s
 capy\
```

So then I searched around and I tried using this:

```
 pip3 install scapy-python3
```

But it just says that pip3 isnt a command, so im not sure what to do

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587507/how-to-install-pip-with-python-3

Comment: Make sure you have pip3 installed properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of pip3 use pip

```
pip install scapy-python3
```

It worked for me. `pip3` is usually used if you have both python2 and python3 installed on your machine. It is uesd to distinguish between different `pip`s in your system.

The `pip3.exe` will be in `python3x/scripts/`.

Check if there is a `pip3.exe` is available in your `scripts` folder.
If the above solution doesn't work for you then try giving the full path of correct `pip.exe`.