# sudo install - Python 3?

Tags: python, linux, installation, sudo

I'm new to Linux and I'm trying to install packages through a Makefile so users can run my Python 3 program.

`sudo pip install python3-weather-api`

However, even after uninstalling a previously installed version, the package seems to be going to the 2.7 version of Python.

```
Requirement already satisfied: python3-weather-api in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

Then, when I run the program, it can't find the module (it works locally in Python 3 just fine).

```
 SystemExit: 1
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "project.py", line 11, in <module>
     from weather import Weather
 ImportError: No module named 'weather'
```

Is there a way I can point the original installation so when I run `python3 project.py` it can find the module?

Thanks very much!

Comment: use `pip3 install python3-weather-api`

Comment: Thanks all - I'm sure this shows my ignorance on it, but is it just `pip3 install python3-weather-api`? I tried that and `sudo pip3 install python3-weather-api` but got an error `make: pip3: Command not found`

Comment: This question may help you installing pip3 properly - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587507/how-to-install-pip-with-python-3

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to use pyenv to manage your Python installations, but, for now, try to run: 

`sudo pip3 install python3-weather-api`

Comment: @user6142489 Let me know if this answers helped you somehow.