# Install libs Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I try to install numpy in pycharm 2017.2. But when I choose numpy in Settings -> Project Interpreter, I'm getting error:

Make sure that you use the correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter located at '/usr/bin/python3.5'

Error: Python packaging tool 'pip' not found

What should I do to avoid it?

Comment: You might need to install pip. See if anything in this question helps you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587507/how-to-install-pip-with-python-3

Comment: well, you need to firstly install pip; it seems you don't have pip installed. for python3 you need to install pip3. your information here is minimal; to start with you don't choose numpy for interpreter, you choose python3 in your case python3.5

Comment: Did you try running pip from cmd? Try running `pip install -U pip`.

Comment: Yes, I try. But after that i get ImportError: No module named 'pip'

Answer (score 0):

Go to:

`Preferences` -> `Project Interpreter` -> press plus "`+`" button it will open `Available packages` window -> search `pip` and choose the first one -> press `Install Packages`.

More info: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html

Comment: Could you please describe how you are running your project? By using the green run button in Pycharm UI or from the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

ok you should not need to install pip (check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows))

python 3.4+ ships with pip.

you should firstly make sure your python is on your PATH if you are on windows.

secondly, in Pycharm you should do: File > Settings > Project > Project Interpreter, in the dropdown select your python installation path and click apply and ok.

once all of this are set up correctly, you should go on to your command line, and type `pip3 install --upgrade numpy`.