# I can't get pip to run in cmd for python even though I extracted it and downloaded it. How do I run it so it doesn't get any errors?

Tags: python-3.x, pip

This is the error I keep getting in command prompt: **'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,**

I get this error when I run something in cmd that looks like this: pip install matplotlib,  or pip install requests, ...

I did everything in this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UKXx4e9PotI&index=14&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDe8XSftW-RAxdo6OmaeL85M) and (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jnpC_Ib_lbc&index=15&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDe8XSftW-RAxdo6OmaeL85M), but I still can't get it. Can anybody help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install pip with Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587507/how-to-install-pip-with-python-3)

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/a/23709194/7976758

Answer (score 0):

Since you say `cmd` I take it you're on Windows.

Perhaps the official instructions from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows) might help.