# ModuleNotFoundError while using tqdm after installation in python

Tags: python, pip, tqdm

I'm using a python code using the package tqdm, I installed it with pip

> androiddl@androiddl:~$ pip install tqdm Collecting tqdm   Using cached
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/76/4c/103a4d3415dafc1ddfe6a6624333971756e2d3dd8c6dc0f520152855f040/tqdm-4.30.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Installing collected packages: tqdm Successfully installed tqdm-4.30.0

After this success message when I'm trying to run my python script I have this error :

> androiddl@androiddl:~/...$
>   python3 download.py "com.facebook.katana" Traceback (most recent call
>   last):   File "download.py", line 10, in 
>       from playstore.playstore import Playstore   File "/home/.../playstore/playstore.py",
>   line 12, in 
>       from tqdm import tqdm ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tqdm'

How can I fix it ? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like `pip` is hooked up to Python 2, and not `python3`, which is what you are using to run your script. Try using `pip3` instead. If that doesn't work, a quick way to solve it is to use `python3 -m pip install ...` for now, although it's nice to have that command located at `pip3`. Try looking at an answer like [How to install pip with Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587507/how-to-install-pip-with-python-3) for that.