# Does the library functions supported by python3.6 be supported by python3.7 also?

Tags: python, pip, python-3.7, can-bus

I installed the CANard library in python3.6 using the following command `pip3 install CANard` which is used for sending and receiving standard CAN message of 8 bytes long using this CANard library I sent a CAN message from the sender side and converted it to a hashed message which is 128 bytes long this 128 bytes long message cannot be sent across the CAN bus as it accepts only 8 bytes of message.

Hence I went to a higher level protocol `can-isotp` which accepts CAN message up to 4096 bytes long.`can-isotp` is supported only by python3.7 but python3.7 does not support the CANard library to send standard CAN message I get the following error when I try to install CANard in python3.7 `pip3.7: command not found`.Similarly, when I try to use the CANard library in python3.7 I get the following error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'canard'`.

I have to perform both the functions send a normal CAN message of 8 bytes long (supported by python3.6) as well as send an extended CAN message of 128 bytes long (supported by python3.7). How can I resolve this problem of python versions?

Comment: Relevant [pip-dealing-with-multiple-python-versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/pip-dealing-with-multiple-python-versions)

Comment: I get the following error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes' when I try to install pip for python 3.7 using the following command sudo python3.7 get-pip.py

Comment: Read [How to install pip with Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6587528/7414759)