# How do I install pip3 for Python3 without root privileges on CentOS 7.6?

Tags: python, installation, pip, centos

I am accessing an external computer running on CentOS 7.6 where I don't have root privileges, thus installing `pip3` using `sudo apt-get install pip3` doesn't work. I tried `yum install python36-setuptools` according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587507/how-to-install-pip-with-python-3) but this command requires me to be root as well. So what can I do now?

Comment: you can create a virtual environment for yourself and install the required packages and dependencies

Comment: `apt-get` is for Debian-derived systems; CentOS is derived from Red Hat, so the `yum` command would be correct if you had the privileges.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29369079/874188 explains how to do this in a virtual environment, which removes the necessity to run anything as a privileged user.