# How to install dbfread in python 3.7.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to install dbfread in Python to read a database in Visual Foxpro, but when I import in my code I get this error below any suggestions why?

File "C:\Python37-32\pr_import.py", line 6, in 
    from dbfread import DBF
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dbfread'

```
    from dbfread import DBF
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Open Command prompt

2.You should try

```
  $ pip install dbfread
```

3. if it doesnt work get .whl file from [Here](https://pypi.org/project/dbfread/)

then install by using

```
pip install "Path file downloaded".whl
```

Answer (score 0):

You should install this package first before importing it.

```
$ pip install dbfread
```

If you already install it, try uninstall and reinstall again.

Comment: My Python folder is in my local disk drive how do I access it from command line?

Comment: What do you mean by Python folder? Do you mean the folder that you wrote the .py script?

Comment: No my folder where I first installed Python so I can pip install

Comment: How did you install python? By the installer from python.org website? If yes, the Python program already install **in** your computer. And next, you should install pip package: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587507/how-to-install-pip-with-python-3 After that, open your commander, type `pip install dbfread`, and it doesn't matter where you do it. After that, you should be able to run the python file without error.

Comment: Or do you install python with anaconda?

Comment: @user13470314 You're welcome. If that helps, you can press the check button next to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem under Linux - the code worked under Python2.

pip3 install dbfread-2.0.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl

helped.

P.S. From the command line, try:

dir c:\pip*.* /s