# download pip3 for python 3.9.0

Tags: python

when i run `python3 -V` on my amazon workdsace - it gives me `Python 3.9.0`
and when i run `python -V`  - it gives me `Python 2.7.18`

and when i run `pip --version` - it gives me `pip 20.2.4 from /home/myName/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)`

what i want is to download pip3 for python 3.9.0 to download modules also the script i made works with python3 not python2

any idea ?

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587507/how-to-install-pip-with-python-3

Comment: it gives me  Loaded plugins: amzn_workspaces_filter_updates, halt_os_update_check,
              : priorities, update-motd
76 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
No package python34-pip available.

Comment: Does ``python3 -m pip`` work for you?

Comment: it gives me usr/local/bin/python3: No module named pip.__main__; 'pip' is a package and cannot be directly executed

Comment: What happens if you type `pip3` into the terminal?

Comment: bash: /usr/bin/pip3: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your distribution here are the commands for CentOS and Debian/Ubuntu:
Centos: `yum install python3-pip`
Debian: `apt install python3-pip`
(you can found command for others Distributions here https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-linux-tools/#installing-pip-setuptools-wheel-with-linux-package-managers)

Or you can install directly from the python script provided by pip developers (not recommended if you have installed your python from OS package manager):
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#installing-with-get-pip-py

Comment: i edited the question  - i have pip for python2 and i want it for python3