# How do I install pip on linux for Python 3.10.9

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, pip, raspberry-pi

I was using `sudo apt-get install python3-pip` to get pip with older versions of Python, but as I understand I have to install a newer version of pip using some different approach because it is not uptodate using apt. I am using an Ubuntu pc and a Raspberry pi for reference, Many posts about this but what is the currently accepted approach as of Jan 2023? Thanks!

EDIT:

Using `pip -V` informes that it is using pip 20.3.4 (python 3.9)

I have Python 3.10.9 installed, and the console informs me version 22.3.1 is also installed

```
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (22.3.1)
```

Anyone know how to use version 22.3.1 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install pip with Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587507/how-to-install-pip-with-python-3)

Answer (score 0):

did you tested `get-pip.py`?

simply download it from [here](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py), and run

```
python get-pip.py
```

Comment: I didn't think clicking that link would download something right away, thank you for the answer but could you link to the download page so I know what it is you linked me

Comment: Here is the github description on `get-pio.py`: https://github.com/pypa/get-pip , and as a side note, the link i dropped in the answer was from pypa, the official holder and maintainer of `pip`. So it's the genuine way to initialize pip for a python binary.

Comment: It works for any python version greater than 3.7

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience with Raspberry Pi, it should be straightforward with `apt install`.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Verify the version:

```
pip3 --version
```

Odoo Forum Reference: https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/how-to-install-pip-in-python-3-on-ubuntu-18-04-167715

Comment: By default it shipped with Python 3.9 but I updated it to 3.10 so that's my main concern, I was having issues using some updated packages yesterday so I figured I might be using a wrong version of pip

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get install python3-pip` and then use

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip to upgrade pip
```

or you can do that.

```
sudo python3.10.9 -m pip install pip
```

Comment: Running your second command spit out ```Requirement already satisfied: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (22.3.1)```

So I guess pip is already downloaded but I need to update something somewhere to be using it