# What the equivalent for 'gem' in python?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does python have a package/module management system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436731/does-python-have-a-package-module-management-system)

In ruby I can do something like

```
gem install my-cool-gem
```

How do I do this in python?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are looking for [PyPi - the Python Package Index.](http://pypi.python.org/pypi).

You do:

```
pip install package
```

Comment: ... after you `easy_install` (or `apt-get`) `pip`, that is.

Comment: @larsmans Indeed, but the PyPI site explains that. In my case ``pacman -S python-pip``.

Comment: The official instructions for installing PIP can be found [here](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html).

Answer (score 5):

If you have [setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) installed then you can use [easy_install](http://packages.python.org/distribute/easy_install.html). Both obtain packages from PyPI I guess. pip is [preferred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220404/why-use-pip-over-easy-install) over easy_install though.