# Python equivalent of a ruby Gem file

Tags: python, ruby, sinatra, gemfile

So I have a ruby sinatra program that runs on a server and I have a Gem file to ensure all its dependancies are installed. However it calls a python script which has its own python module dependancies. Thus when it deploy to server all the ruby gems dependancies are fine but not they python dependancies.

Is there a python equivalent of a Gem file? Or is there a way for me to install the python modules via the Gem file?

buildr has been suggested to me but that seems to be for a java based program.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What the equivalent for 'gem' in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331430/what-the-equivalent-for-gem-in-python)

Comment: You can also look at this tutorial: http://www.jontourage.com/2011/02/09/virtualenv-pip-basics/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Installing packages (gem install)

```
pip install mypackage
```

Dependencies and bulk-install(gemfile)

Use pip's requirements.txt files. It's a txt document of the required packages with 
any version contraints. Example:

```
django==1.5
fabric>1.2
South==0.7.3
```

You would then install those dependencies with:

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

You can then execute those files after install. Example:

```
$ pip install gunicorn
$ gunicorn -h
```

Package gems for install. For that, there is `pip bundle` and `pip zip/unzip`

That's the only way I know to bundle and deploy dependencies with python. Hope that helps.