# ImportError: No module named 'requests'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Getting this error when trying to run a Python script. I have downloaded a requests-1.2.0 folder but I have no idea what to do with it. I've tried running the setup.py file contained in the download but it just opens a command terminal for a second and closes.

I am running Python from my Windows desktop, not on a server or anything like that.

No idea what I'm doing here!

Comment: did you do python setup.py install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the root directory of the requests folder you downloaded, run:

```
$ python setup.py install
```

then it will be installed system-wide, and your scripts may use "import requests"

Answer (score 4):

You need to install it for the same version of Python that you're using to run your script. The `setup.py` tells Python how to do that, so you can open up a command line to that directory (do you know how to do that?) and type `python setup.py install` to install it.

But there's a much easier way -- Python has an excellent package manager, called [pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436731/does-python-have-a-package-module-management-system/13445719#13445719). You can use that to install any other Python packages that you want by typing `pip install requests` at the command line. In particular, it will connect to the internet and work out what to download, then download and install it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to run setup.py with the "install" argument.  That will install requests in the site-packages folder where it can be imported globally.

Open a cmd window and navigate to the requests folder that you downloaded.  Then type the following into the cmd window:

```
C:\python27\python.exe setup.py install
```

You'll need to change the path to the python executable to match that for your system, of course.

PS: You're going to love requests!