# Python - ImportError: No module named 'requests'

Tags: python, python-requests

I get this error when running code, so it appears that requests hasn't installed properly. I am running Windows 7 32-bit system with Python 3.3.

When I go into 'Programs and Features' in windows it shows up as installed.

I installed this program from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ and I have also downloaded the requests folder and tried installing it this way, I can't seem to get this to work.

I have visited [ImportError: No module named 'requests'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16265368/importerror-no-module-named-requests) already, but I didn't find this helped at all.

I keep seeing the following statement, but I am uncertain of how to run this?

```
$ python setup.py install
```

Please help!?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer there is clear. But let me explain to you as good as I can. This error comes because requests module is not installed in your system

Download the requests module to your system from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests#downloads)

And extract it. Go to your command prompt/terminal and reach to the folder you downloaded.There, you will see `setup.py`, the file that you need to execute to install the requests module.

```
python setup.py install
```

Installs the requests module

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
$ python setup.py install
```

It's a command line in a terminal in Linux or the alike. My guess is that you could do the same opening a terminal in Windows pressing the start key and typing 'cmd', without quotes of course. If you had python already install the %PATH% variable should be set up properly and it should just run. Well, perhaps you need to go to the same folder as the setup.py using

```
> cd path_to_file
```

And then,

```
> python setup.py install
```

I hope it helps. Let me know otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ubuntu, there is need to install requests

run this command:

`pip install requests`

if you face permission denied error, use sudo before command:

`sudo pip install requests`