# How to install selenium package using pip on Windows XP?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pip, windows-xp-sp3

I am running Windows XP SP3 where I installed Python-3.4.1. I want to install [selenium] webdriver[2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) package using pip. I set the path variable of python in the right way on Window XP, so using CMD I run successfully python command. However, when I run pip install selenium it says that my command is unkown. From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436731/does-python-have-a-package-module-management-system/13445719#13445719), I saw that PIP is embedded in Python-3.4.1.
How can I install selenium package using pip (or any other means) ? Should I declare the path variable to pip ? If yes, where to find pip ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find pip in: `Path_to_Python_Home_Directory\C:\Python34\Scripts\pip.exe` 
Since you added a path environment variable to Python, I suppose you know how to do it for pip :)
Now you can install selenium this way: `Path_to_Python_Home_Directory\C:\Python34\Scripts\pip.exe install selenium`, OR: `pip install selenium` if you set its path environment variable.

[image]

More details on [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html) if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install pip in windows system
so you can find pip.exe for that
and using that you can easily install selenium

other way is to install selenium is easy_install selenium

Answer (score 0):

we can directly use the python command with pip option to install further packages as following, without the need of setting pip in path environment:-

**C:\ python -m pip install python_module_name**

**C:\ python -m pip install selenium**

This will install the module using pip.

Answer (score 0):

## To Install selenium use this command including --User.

```
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade --user selenium
```