# Can't open C:\Python27\Scripts\pip-scripts.py

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

What should I do? Reinstall pip? pip-scripts.py file, is not any more in the directory, I don't know what happened. 
Can't install/uninstall other modules. How can I fix it? I am using windows 7.

Comment: Maybe you should give some more information.

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear. I have installed pip some time ago and I have installed some modules. I wanted to install Django and it turned "Can't open C:\Python27\Scripts\pip-scripts.py"    What should I do? I wanted to uninstall pip, to install it again, but says the same thing.

Comment: I'm sorry I am very bad at Python but I was just mentioning it for other people, so they can help you maybe.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

What you can do:

- Python versions [python 2.7.9+](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.7.html#pep-477-backport-ensurepip-pep-453-to-python-2-7) and [python 3.4+](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.4.html) ship with `pip`. So you can choose any of them to avoid the hassle of getting pip and stuff. But...
- I think you don't have any special reason to use python 2.7. So I suggest you remove python 2.7, [download](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-350/) and install python 3.5 and start using it! As they say: *Python 2.x is legacy, Python 3.x is the present and future of the language*. [Read more](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3).
- Then you can install/uninstall any package using `pip`, as pip is the default [package manager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13445719/3375713) in newer versions of python. Read pip [docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/).