# How to install pyatspi?

Tags: python

I'm using ldtp and while I import it ,my idle jump out with a error:

```
from ldtp import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ldtpd/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
from xmlrpc_daemon import XMLRPCLdtpd
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ldtpd/xmlrpc_daemon.py",line 25, in <module>
import core
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ldtpd/core.py", line 24, in <module>
from pyatspi import findDescendant, Registry
ImportError: No module named pyatspi
```

And then I yum install pyatspi but found

```
No package pyatspi available.
```

Then I download pyatspi-2.20.0.tar.xz

During ./configure ,an error occurs as

```
configure: error: Package requirements (pygobject-3.0 >= 2.90.1) were not met:
No package 'pygobject-3.0' found
```

So I go back and try to install pygobject and found:

```
configure: error: Package requirements (glib-2.0 >= 2.24.0
gobject-introspection-1.0 >= 1.29.0
) were not met:
No package 'gobject-introspection-1.0' found
```

Excuse me ???

Is that the same thing we all have to suffer during install pyatspi???

What should I do to jump out from this nightmare?

Thanks for any help !

Comment: You should use a package manager such as `pip` or `conda`. See also [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13445719/1328439)

Comment: @DmitriChubarov Thanks for you kindly reply . I tried with your suggestion but it make no effect :  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyatspi (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pyatspi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pyatspi` is a part of GNOME. What you got involved into by building pyatspi from source was leading you into building a significant part of GNOME from source. No easy task at all.

Your best bet is to find AT SPI package for your distribution. You did not specify what linux distribution do you have. But for most common distributions such packages exist.

First make sure you have got `python-gobject` installed

For rpm-based distributions

```
 rpm -q python-gobject
```

For dpkg-based:

```
 dpkg -s python-gobject
```

Install it if necessary.

Next install a package containing pyatspi for your distribution.
For instance for OpenSUSE you need to install python-atspi

```
zypper in python-atspi
```

For Ubuntu and derivatives it is `python-pyatspi`:

```
apt-get install python-pyatspi
```

For RedHat, Fedora and derivatives it is at-spi-python

```
yum install at-spi-python
```

Having got that you should be able to type

```
python -c "import gi,pyatspi"
```

Comment: Thanks ! But how can I obtain python-gobject package? I'm using RHEL6.8 and after I input "rpm -q python-gobject" my terminal response as "package python-gobject is not installed" .  Yum nor pip could find a python-gobject package.

Comment: BY the way , the terminal told me :"Package pygobject2-2.20.0-5.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version" Maybe it is same with python-object?

Comment: Sorry for bother you but I also found "Package at-spi-python-1.28.1-2.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version" So why my ldtp told me no module named pyatspi ?

Comment: None of this works for virtual environments, which is how most Python apps are run.

Comment: @Cerin well, since pyatspi is a python wrapper around Gnome AT-SPI library, you would need to get gnome libs in your venv. By the way this post is almost 5 years old and things might have changed since.