# Equivalent of pywinauto library for debian

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, raspberry-pi3, pywinauto

I'm looking for an equivalent Python library that will work when I run my script on Raspberry Pi. I'm under the impression that pywinauto only works on windows machine. 
I want to control some inputs to a GUI launched by my script, using my script. Apart from pywinauto I have no idea how to do this. I thought about using command line to control the software directly, but if there is a simpler way I would really appreciate knowing about it.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Do you have ATSPI registry daemon on your RaspPi?

Comment: We’re working to support ATSPI in pywinauto this year! It should work perfectly on Ubuntu and somewhat on other linuxes.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov What is that? I've never heard of that before. What does it do?

Answer (score 0):

ATSPI is an Linux accessibility technology to obtain GUI text/rectangle properties programmatically. See [how to find and run ATSPI registry daemon and how to enable ATSPI for the most popular types of GUI apps](http://florence.sourceforge.net/english/how-to.html). Usually it's

```
$ /usr/libexec/at-spi-registryd &
```

There is a Python bindings for ATSPI. See this answer for details:
[How to install pyatspi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40799953/how-to-install-pyatspi)

The pyatspi package has too many dependencies like pygobject etc. It also requires some compilation during installation steps. We think this is not user friendly so we decided to use `libatspi.so` directly (without any dependencies). This work status can be tracked here: https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/pull/449

There is no exact deadline for pywinauto 0.7.0 with this feature (it's a hobby project), but I would say this summer sounds realistic.