# How to import python packages?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, importerror

I'm new to Python and need to use a python-based tool called chromosomer that imports some python packages including bioformats. Bioformats has many modules including bed. On running chromosomer, I get the error:

```
smeeta:~$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import chromosomer
>>> from chromosomer.cli import bioformats
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/chromosomer/cli.py", line 8, in <module>
    import bioformats.bed
ImportError: No module named bed
>>> import bioformats
>>> import bioformats.bed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named bed
>>>
```

How do I install the package chromosomer and its dependent packages ?

Comment: Thanks for the edit and the answers below; but I've already installed chromosomer and its dependencies using sudo -E pip install --index-url=http://pypi.python.org/simple/ -r requirements.txt. After doing this, I had to add /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/<package_name>/ to PYTHONPATH in my bashrc. I'm still getting the import error mentioned above..

Comment: 'from chromosomer.cli import chromosomer' worked fine for me, see last section of my answer. My suggestion here is, remove/uninstall the chromosomer package and also the path line from bashrc - then re-install it.

Answer (score 3):

Use `pip`

E.g.

```
#>pip install <desired package>
#>pip install chromosomer
```

Official `pip` documentation [link](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/).

**For Python 2.7.9+ and 3.4+**
  It should come preinstalled with `pip`

**Python 2 ≤ 2.7.8 and Python 3 ≤ 3.3**
Follow the instructions from here :   https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#do-i-need-to-install-pip

For more discussion about this question:
[Does Python have a package/module management system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436731/does-python-have-a-package-module-management-system)

Answer (score 1):

So in python most of things gets installed using the `pip` command ,recommended tool for installing Python packages.

Also did you tried :

```
pip install python-bioformats
```

Comment: Yup have installed python-bioformats also; but doesn't solve my issue

Answer (score 0):

For any packages other than default ones, you need to install them before import/using them.

The most common and convenient way for installing a Python package is via the [`pip`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pip_(package_manager)) package management utility.

1.**Install pip**:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip  # for Debian/Ubuntu
sudo yum -y install python-pip  # for CentOS/RHEL
```

**Note**: For Python 2.7.9+ and 3.4+ `pip` comes pre-installed.

---

2.**Install python packages**:

```
sudo pip install chromosomer
```

It'll install `bioinformats`, `future`, `pyfaidx`, `PyVCF`, `six` packages as dependencies.
**Note**: no need for `sudo` if already `root` user, or using a `vitualenv`.

**Verification** - can verify the installation using `pip freeze` command:

```
(venv_bioinformatics)[nahmed@localhost virtualenvs]$ pip freeze
bioformats==0.1.14
chromosomer==0.1.3
future==0.16.0
pyfaidx==0.4.8.1
PyVCF==0.6.8
six==1.10.0
wheel==0.24.0
```

**Test** - I installed the chromosomer and imported, worked fine:

```
(venv_bioinformatics)[nahmed@localhost virtualenvs]$ python 
Python 2.7.5 (default, Sep 15 2016, 22:37:39) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from chromosomer.cli import chromosomer
>>>
```

Comment: did you try the importing in Python shell ? and also tally the package versions with the ones I have shared, as it worked fine for me.

Comment: Also, if I import just the package, it gets imported, but if I try to access a module, it throws up the error..

Comment: kindly, share the full session i.e the traceback(error) and the import statement causing the issues. Add it in the question as Edit 1: (below the current content)

Comment: Yes, in Python shell, the packages are getting imported smoothly but not their modules.. `import <package_name>` doesn't give any error while `from <package_name> import module` throws up the error.. And yes, the versions of most of the installed packages are same except six==1.5.2 and Python is 2.7.6..