# Installing PIL to use with Django on Mac OS X

Tags: python, django, macos, python-imaging-library

I'm really annoyed by installation of PIL (Python Imaging Library) on Mac OS X 10.6. Does anyone have it installed and could post the recipe here? I've tried a lot of them posted here on this site and a lot from google, but always anding with missing some part and can't work normally with PIL...

Thanks in advance.
Ignas

Comment: OK guys, got some answers will try it later this week. Hope that some of them will work :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**EDIT:** This answer has been getting voted up recently, and I want to modify it to reflect what I'm doing now.

Firstly, I've switched from MacPorts to [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) for package management on Mac OS X. Secondly, I've switched from using my package manager to using [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/) and [virtualenvwrapper](https://doughellmann.com/projects/virtualenvwrapper/) to manage my Python libraries.

**Why I switched:**

At first, with just a few Django projects, it was very easy to keep everything up to date using MacPorts. It was also fairly easy to have multiple versions of Python using `python_select`. What I didn't realize was that I was doing a pretty terrible job of keeping multiple libraries working side-by-side. It became obvious as I upgraded my packages that sometimes I **really** didn't want a project's Django version to change. After a couple of Django 1.1 projects (now running Django 1.3) started exhibiting weird behaviour (forms failing to submit because of CSRF middleware changes, small differences in Django libraries, admin app assets changing, and so on) it became clear that I should look into a better solution.

**What I do now:**

On Mac OS X I'm moved over to using pip and virtualenvwrapper. First off, I install virtualenvwrapper:

```
pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

This will grab virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper. You then need to add the following to your `.bashrc` or `.profile` and `source` it or open a new shell.

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh # where Homebrew places it
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV_ARGS='--no-site-packages' # optional
```

Line 1 sets up the variable `workon` needs to find its files. Line 2 points to the main shell script (the path here is where Homebrew places the file, it might be different if you're using another package manager). Line 3 is optional, but I really like it: it makes sure that no currently installed libraries in the "main" site-packages repository will leak into your newly created virtual environment. I find this keeps things clean and leads to fewer surprises down the road as things are upgraded.

The next step is to create a new virtual environment:

```
mkvirtualenv testEnvironmentName
```

After making the environment, you'll be placed into it. If you kept the `--no-site-packages` flag, you can type `pip freeze` to see that your Python library slate is now blank. To escape from the virtual environment, use the `deactivate` command. To get into your virtualenv again, use `workon testEnvironmentName`. Note that you can use tab completion on the name of the environment. Also note that typing `workon` by itself will give you a list of available environments. From here you can `pip install` any libraries you want, including PIL.

To learn more about virtualenvwrapper, [I recommend checking out the documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20120710062619/http://www.doughellmann.com:80/docs/virtualenvwrapper/).

[Here's another great resource which taught me a lot about using virtualenvwrapper](https://web.archive.org/web/20161126183524/http://mathematism.com:80/2009/07/30/presentation-pip-and-virtualenv/) ([or just view the screencast](https://vimeo.com/5894881))

---

**ORIGINAL:**

You can also instal PIL using [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/). The package name is `py-pil`. [Here's more information on the package](http://py-pil.darwinports.com/). I'm pretty fond of MacPorts over pip, as I find it gives me a bit more configurability when it comes to keeping several versions of python and several libraries installed.

Here are the installation instructions for MacPorts: http://www.macports.org/install.php

See also: [What is the most compatible way to install python modules on a Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213690/what-is-the-most-compatible-way-to-install-python-modules-on-a-mac/1213823#1213823)

Answer (score 14):

Following steps worked for me:

```
$ brew install pip
$ export ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64"
$ pip install pil
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, I have issues with `PIL` on `10.6.6` too, `homebrew` and `easy_install`.

The easiest solution for me was to `easy_install PIL` / `pip install PIL`, navigate to `/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/`, and symlink the `PIL-1.1.7-.....egg` file to `PIL`

```
ln -s PIL-................egg PIL


>>> import PIL
>>> from PIL import Image
# no more problems.
```

Edit: These days, I try to use Pillow, a library built to help install PIL. Try `pip install pillow` - can't hurt!

Comment: It seems that this one worked, but I guess it also helped that I had libjpeg installed before (for work with jpg files). I did it by using few different recipes... Can't say which one was the right one... Thanks for this simple two step setup. Maybe I missed symlink last times I've tried easy_install...

Answer (score 5):

It might be easier to pinpoint your issue if you can elaborate on what you tried and what error messages were generated with those attempts. Here's some probable solutions that you may or may not have attempted:

```
pip install pil
```

if you dont have [pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip), try

```
easy_install pil
```

Since you're on the Mac, you can also get HomeBrew (a package manager) and then try

```
brew install pil
```

or [Macports](http://www.macports.org) has a [PIL package here](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=library&substr=py-pil).

Or build from [source](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/)?

More importantly, the PIL README states,

*--------------------------------------------------------------------

### Additional notes for Mac OS X

On Mac OS X you will usually install additional software such as
libjpeg or freetype with the "fink" tool, and then it ends up in
"/sw".  If you have installed the libraries elsewhere, you may have
to tweak the "setup.py" file before building.*

That could be your issue. Good luck!

Comment: yes, easy_install worked and I also did as Yuji suggested - created symlink "ln -s PIL-................egg PIL" in site-packages directory. And of course I installed libjpeg to work with jpg files (but I did in few different ways, so can't say which one worked for me...). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

After fresh OS installation tried these steps:

1. Installed [homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew)
2. brew install libjpeg
3. brew install pil
4. easy_install pil
5. cd /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages
6. ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/pil/1.1.7/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PIL PIL

After that I was able to load and save jpeg files... I know that this issue has a lot of different solutions and I'm not 100% my way will work for other, but it's worth to try if you just bumping your head in to the wall :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm using OS X 10.5.8, gcc 4.2.1, python 2.7.5, libjpegv9 and Pillow 2.1.0 (which is based on PIL).

My problem apparently (but it's just a guess) was caused by architecture incompatibilities of the libjpeg and python (and Pillow) builds.

Building python and libjpeg from source using only 32bit arch solved it. I installed all the other python libraries, Pillow included, just by using

```
pip install xxxxx
```

and it worked fine.

### Details

First I tried both a dmg from the python.org site and a universal build installed via macports. I had not specified universal when installing but macports installed both i386 and ppc architectures anyways.

That caused me problems because libjpeg compiles only to i386 by default.

To check the build of the binaries, I did:

```
file /usr/bin/python
```

/usr/bin/python: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures

/usr/bin/python: Mach-O executable i386

/usr/bin/python: Mach-O executable ppc

```
file /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.dylib
```

/usr/local/lib/libjpeg.dylib: Mach-O dynamically linked shared library i386

When building PIL (or Pillow), it seemed to use the same build options as python "-gcc i386 -gcc ppc" (which seems logical).

All went well until it built the "_imaging" module. There, it showed a warning that libjpeg.dylib was not of the right architecture but in the end it showed that JPEG was available just the same.

Answer (score 1):

There is a packaging fork of PIL that attempts to make it easier to install and support on many modern platforms, including OS X:

- http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/1.6

You should be able to install it on OS X with pip or easy_install (assuming you have XCode). If you have any trouble, please open a ticket here:

- https://github.com/collective/Pillow/issues

Answer (score 0):

Hey check out this [article](http://cgarvey.ie/blog/archive/2010/01/27/installing-pil-on-mac-os-x-snow-leopard-for-use-in-google-app-engine/), worked wonders for me on Snow Leopard.

I'd also recommend using [libjpeg 0.6](ftp://ftp.uni-leipzig.de/pub/linux/ftp%3Arobot.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/Sources/System/Libs/jpegsrc.v6b.tar.gz) instead of 0.7 noted in the article.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I have issues installing PIL with brew and easy_install on my Mac too. My solution is to download source code from http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/, extract the tar ball and use

```
python setup.py install
```

to compile and install the package.