# Installed Python from Package, Terminal didn't update?

Tags: python

Terminal is still showing Python 2.7.2 after an install of 3.3.0

I'm new to python- just want to get a good development environment working on Mac 10.8.

Comment: use `python3` instead of `python`

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: That's an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `python3` instead of `python`:

```
$ python3
Python 3.2.3 (default, Oct 19 2012, 19:53:57) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Comment: thank you. i'll accept when SO lets me in 12 minutes :) cheers

Comment: If you're new then I would suggest you to use [IPython](http://ipython.org/), it provides some additional features compared to normal python shell.

Comment: i'm doing some looking around, would you also recommending using pip for installing modules or should i try to use macports. i'm a front-end web developer so this is all a new world for me

Comment: I am not a mac user, so can't say anything about that. This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213690/what-is-the-most-compatible-way-to-install-python-modules-on-a-mac

Answer (score 5):

See [PEP 394](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/):

> This PEP provides a convention to ensure that Python scripts can continue to be portable across *nix systems, regardless of the default version of the Python interpreter (i.e. the version invoked by the python command).
>
> - `python2` will refer to some version of Python 2.x
> - `python3` will refer to some version of Python 3.x
> - `python` should refer to the same target as python2 but may refer to python3 on some bleeding edge distributions

You have Python 2 and Python 3 installed, so the `python` command refers to `python2`. If you want Python 3, do it explicitly with the `python3` command.

Answer (score 0):

You have few options

1. In your bash `~/.bash_profile` add `alias python='python3'`
2. Instead of using `python` command use `python3` instead.
3. Install python3 via homebrew