# Failed matplotlib installation (tried everything) on (OS X 10.8.4 & Python 2.7.5)

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib

I'm a little new at this, but have honestly exhausted every thread and possible installation option to have run into an error or issue every time.

Could list multiple issues experienced, but the main one:

```
 pip install matplotlib

 error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib': Permission denied
```

Could anybody help me figure out how to change these permissions or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Here is a link on installing modules for Macs which has a few good options you may want to look at. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213690/what-is-the-most-compatible-way-to-install-python-modules-on-a-mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have admin rights you can do

`sudo pip install matplotlb`

It will prompt for your password, and when you enter it you will be able to install there.

Another option is to install locally with the `--user` flag for `pip`

`pip install --user matplotlib`

Another option is to go with a scientific distribution like [Enthought Canopy](https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/) or the [Anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/v) python distribution from Continuum Analytics. Both of these come with matplotlib (and a lot of other very useful packages) already installed and working properly.