# How to override OSX's version of numpy when I import in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I'd like to use numpy 1.9 without deleting the version of numpy (1.8) that came with my Mac:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.version.version
'1.8.0rc1'
>>> numpy.__file__
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/__init__.pyc'
```

Since that version of numpy is in `System`, I'd rather not delete it. That said, `pip` recognizes that I have numpy 1.9 installed but I don't know how to reference it in my `import` statement.

```
$ pip list
...
numpy (1.9.0)
...
```

Thoughts?

Comment: I'll try to help.  Where did that 1.9 get installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to note that there are two different installations of Python on your Mac. There is the System Python (`/usr/bin`), and also the `/usr/local/bin` python.

There are also two installations of pip. For example:

```
$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/pip
lrwxr-xr-x  1 dmao  admin  30 Feb 14 19:09 /usr/local/bin/pip -> ../Cellar/python/2.7.9/bin/pip
```

This is the homebrew pip. I assume you have numpy installed on the homebrew version of pip.

**There is no System version of pip installed by default**. The usual solution is to run `easy_install pip` and install a system version of pip, then `pip install numpy` (using system pip). However, you mentioned you wanted to leave the system numpy.

---

If you need to leave the system numpy untouched, you can run the `/usr/local` Python as your default Python instead of the system Python. Here we create a symbolic link from the default python to the local python, so that the local python becomes the default.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/python
```

Then your default Python version becomes the one which matches your default version of pip.

You can restore your default Python version anytime by replacing the symlink. /usr/bin has the links you need.

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/ | grep python
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root   wheel        76 Feb 21  2014 pythonw2.5 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/bin/pythonw2.5
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root   wheel        76 Feb 21  2014 pythonw2.6 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/pythonw2.6
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root   wheel        76 Feb 21  2014 pythonw2.7 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pythonw2.7
```

---

Alternatively, if your System Python is being used for something, and/or you need to keep switching between versions of python packages, you could use [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv), which makes this much easier.

---

There are many different ways to manage python modules on a Mac. For example, [What is the most compatible way to install python modules on a Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213690/what-is-the-most-compatible-way-to-install-python-modules-on-a-mac)

Comment: This is pretty dumb, but I wasn't using `virtualenv` correctly. I assumed that any Python executing in a directory with a `virtualenv` subdirectory automatically pulled dependencies from the `virtualenv`. Once I activated the env, installed numpy 1.9 and then executed my code, I was fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone reaching this in 2018, the proper way to do this is to make sure your brew packages folder precedes system packages folder in PATH:

1. `Brew install <mypackage>` - `python` or `numpy` in this case
2. Test that your brew package is now being found instead of system package by typing `which <package>` in terminal. It should say `/usr/local/bin/<package>` instead of `/usr/bin/<package>`.
3. ***Explanation***: System packages are found in `/usr/bin` while brew packages start in `/usr/local/..` e.g `/usr/local/bin`, `/usr/local/opt/<package>/bin`.
4. If system package is being found instead, test your PATH order by typing `echo $PATH` in your terminal. Is `/usr/local/..` appearing earlier than system path?
5. If not, you need to make sure `/usr/local/bin` comes first before `/usr/bin` so that the brew-installed executable is found before the system executable.
6. To edit PATH: Run `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` in terminal and also put it in `~/.bash_profile` config file to make it permanent
7. Test your PATH changes worked (`echo $TEST`), and that your brew package is being found instead of system package (`which <package>`)
8. ***General Info***: Brew will install packages in `/usr/local/Cellar/..` and symbolically link the binaries (executables) to `/usr/local/bin` files
9. ***Troubleshooting***: Note that Brew can sometimes install packages with non-standard names like `Python3`, `gcc-7` etc. So even if you have `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin` in your PATH, when you test with `which python` it will still point to `/usr/bin/<package>`. In this case you need to manually create a symlink in your `/usr/local/bin` with the expected executable name. E.g in `/usr/local/bin` do `ln -s python3 python`