# Install python module on mac osx (qpid proton)

Tags: python, macos, pip, qpid

Im new to python programming and have some difficulties while installing modules. I have installed mysql connector for python on mac and that worked just fine. Now Im trying to install qpid proton on mac http://qpid.apache.org/proton/.

Qpid does not have an installer like mysql, so I have to install it manually. Documenation really lacks. I have searched SO but easy_install or pip like described here does not seem to work for me. 
[What is the most compatible way to install python modules on a Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213690/what-is-the-most-compatible-way-to-install-python-modules-on-a-mac)

"PIP install proton" only installs part of the library, as said here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-qpid-proton/0.8.2

How do I install this library on mac?

Answer (score 2):

If you still care there python-qpid-proton is now on pypi: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-qpid-proton

So just run

```
pip install python-qpid-proton
```

On Mac you may have issues during installation to find openssl libs.
Use brew to install openssl first:

```
brew install openssl
```

then brew gives a hint:

```
Apple has deprecated use of OpenSSL in favor of its own TLS and crypto libraries

Generally there are no consequences of this for you. If you build your
own software and it requires this formula, you'll need to add to your
build variables:

LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
PKG_CONFIG_PATH: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/pkgconfig
```

So just export these env vars and rerun your favorite pip install (or better to avoid havoc in future add following to your ~/.bash_profile:

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/pkgconfig"
```

This worked for me like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to this: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/qpid/branches/0.20/qpid/python/README.txt

I think that if you download this one: https://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-proton-0.9.1/index.html, you have only to include the file in your project and to don't install nothing. Just use it!

Comment: Thanks for helping. I dont think thats the case, have tried the examples in the download you are suggesting and they dont work (ImportError: No module named proton). Somehow I need to install something to get this working.