# Python Kik Chatbot Struggle

Tags: python, kik

I am trying to develop a kik chatbot with Python.

I am using Pycharm as my IDE.

Here is what I began with:

```
from flask import Flask, request, Response
from kik import kikapi
```

But I keep getting and error, "unresolved reference.." on the "import..." why is this? I've installed both through

```
pip install --user <package name>
```

Thanks

Using a Mac:

**SCREEN**
[image]

SCREN 2:
[image]

Comment: It will be helpful if you can post screenshots. Also, you have not mentioned you dev env, is it Windows / Linux / Mac ? Please do that, otherwise it is difficult to guess what could be wrong.

Comment: @CyprUS, sorry, mac

Comment: Can you post screenshot ? I don't use Mac, but screenshots attract attention. Do you need to add the python path somewhere ?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213690/what-is-the-most-compatible-way-to-install-python-modules-on-a-mac/

Comment: @CyprUS it still says the same exact thing. I;ll post a screnshot

Comment: In the screenshot I see you are trying to install pip through easy_install. Actually, both pip and easy_install are tools to manage package installation. Can you post which package exactly is missing.

Comment: I have no clue.

Comment: @CyprUS, I am dissapointed with Python. Java is much easier to use than this mess.

Comment: Also, did try using a virtualenv ? Using a virtualenv is pretty standard way to not pollute your dev environment with thousand different packages.

Comment: Do you really want to give up so easily ? Being a coder REQUIRES you to be patient.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about Mac setup. But I use `virtualenv` to workaround any package-mess which I sometimes get into.

Referring to this excellent [python doc link](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) , I present the following steps to create a `virtualenv` for ease of use.

NOTE : I dont know PyCharms, I use terminal always to work on PY.

I ran all of this on terminal.

```
pip install virtualenv --> installs virtualenv package
cd <proj-directory>
virtualenv venv -->creates a virtual environment by the name venv
source venv/bin/activate --> activates the virtual environment
pip install kik
deactivate --> come out of the virtual environment
```

NOTE :

1. Doing your project on virtualenv has several advantages, primarily being that you shield your other projects from any version dependencies.
2. Activate your virtual environment everytime you want to work on that particular project, and deactivate it when you are done.