# installing third party modules to mac

Tags: python, macos

[image]I have been struggling to install a third party module for mac.

I spotted a similar question, ([What is the most compatible way to install python modules on a Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213690/what-is-the-most-compatible-way-to-install-python-modules-on-a-mac/))

However I'm getting a syntax error when following this advice.

Could anyone help me out?

[image]

Comment: Syntax error? `easy_install` or `pip` run from the terminal shell, **not** the python interpreter

Comment: Show the actual error *in the question*. That means editing it to add enough information to allow a diagnosis and answer. You might consider temporarily deleting the question (to avoid downvotes or close votes) in the interim, and undeleting it after you're done with the edits.

Comment: You might also consider going through http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, and following the advice therein.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Type `quit()`. Try the command again

Answer (score 0):

You are running Python 3.5 according to the image

`pip` is already available, no need to install it again.

You need to not be within the python interpreter REPL